# Django database problems after pushing to github for heroku to build

Tags: django, heroku

I built my Django website locally, and tested it all locally and everything was working fine so I decided to get it on Heroku. I set it up so that I push it to a github project, then Heroku builds it from there and deploys it to the site. The only problem I'm having is with the database. Here's the setup in my settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=600, ssl_require=True)}
if DATABASES['default'] == {}:
    DATABASES['default'] = {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
```

At the end of the file I have "django_heroku.settings(locals())".
So before I push it to github I clear the migrations folder *only because I've been having problems*, then I add, commit, push, and do the migrate via "heroku run --app app_name python manage.py migrate" which then tells me to do makemigrations before migrate, but I've already done it. So I've no idea what I'm doing wrong. Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `heroku` don't support `sqlite` database, but it supports `Postgress DB`. It does have some restriction on number of rows you can use (run `heroku pg` command after you set up the DB on `heroku` to get the details). I personally find this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6DI_7Zja8Zc) helpful to deploy my django app into `heroku`.